# How to use for loop and add one day (timedelta) every time

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2015,10,1)
today = datetime..today()
oneday = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

date_counter = 0
while not date == today:
    date_counter+=1
    date += oneday
```

In this code I use while loop to achieve my goal--to count the days between today and the specific day chosen by users.

However, I want to use for loop to do the same thing. Can it rewrite by for?

Comment: why is that? Why do you want to use a for loop?

Comment: I am curious if there is any better way used by for loop than mine

Comment: Better approach would be to not use loop for such task in the first place. Also what you are saying is not possible using for loop on python.

Comment: Okay, I just want to know if it is possible! Thank you! You can answer the question and I will give you the best answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help. And done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach that you are using is not advised. The better approach would be to not use a loop in the first place. You can instead try the following code:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2015,10,1)
today = datetime..today()
oneday = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

date_counter = (today - date).days
```

To answer your question about possibility of using for loop. I would say a big no. hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Subtraction of `date`s makes a `timedelta`:

```python
import datetime
date = datetime.date(2015,10,1)
today = datetime.date.today()
date_counter = (today - date).days
```

If you *really* want to use a for loop, however, you can do this:

import datetime

```
date = datetime.date(2015,10,1)
today = datetime.date.today()
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

date_counter = 0

def gen_dates(some_date):
    while some_date != today:
        some_date += one_day
        yield some_date

for d in gen_dates(date):
    date_counter += 1
    print(date_counter, ':', d)
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect so I give you upvote! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code only makes sense if you want to do something for every day in this range.

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2016,2,1)
today = datetime.date.today()
oneday = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

date_counter = 0
for days in range(0, (today - date).days):
     date_counter += 1
     date += oneday
```

If you only need the number of days you can use this

```
date_counter = (today - date).days
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be used also

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2015,10,1)
today = datetime.date.today()
oneday = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

date_counter = 0
l = [1]
for i in l:
    if not date == today:
        date_counter+=1
        date += oneday
        l.append(1)

print date_counter
```

Comment: @NighttimeDriver50000 i know this is not best approach , i gave it alternative way and  to show the list in for loop can be modifyed in for loop

Comment: I know you know; I just applaud you for your creativity.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2015,10,1)
d1 = datetime..today()
delta =  d1 - d0
print delta.days
```

you can easily calculate the date diff using standard function.

```
(today - date).days
```