# How to use for loop specific days from list (datetime.timedelta) and extract to different csv files

Tags: python, for-loop, break, python-datetime

The following code is not correct, since datetime.timedelta(day = " ") must contain the integer not string.

Take an reference from the link [How to use for loop and add one day (timedelta) every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885980/how-to-use-for-loop-and-add-one-day-timedelta-every-time)

It is difficult to define the new function under these situation, any easy and handy way to solve?

**--Solved-- by adding: day=int(day in string format)**

```
def get_data():

    # Every stock can loop on every periods
    stocks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','G','H']

    # since the limitation of API data provider, ~180 days' data can be extracted per request 
    periods = ['0','178','356','534']

    for x in stocks:

        for _ in range(10):
            tws.reqHistoricalData(x)

            for n in periods:

                data = pd.DataFrame(reqHistoricalData(datetime.datetime.today()- datetime.timedelta(days=n)).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))

                # if there are any empty data, it can "smart" loop back and start from corresponding stock AND period without running again from the beginning
                if not data.empty:
                    #1 st Edited
                    data.to_csv("filename"+x+"@"+n+".csv")
                    break

                print("Data is empty")
```

The existing code only export cvs with filenameA@0 , filenameB@0, filenameC@0.....
**However, it can't be exported to different csv files as the following**

```
data.to_csv("filename"+x+"@"+n+".csv")

filenameA@0.csv
filenameA@178.csv 
filenameA@356.csv
filenameA@534.csv
filenameB@0.csv
filenameB@178.csv
filenameB@356.csv
filenameB@534.csv
filenameC@0.csv
..........
```

Comment: why don't use use list with integers `[0, 178, 356, 534]` ? Or use `int()` to convert string to integer.

Comment: BTW: you use loop so you calculate the same values many times - you could create `datetime.datetime.today()` only once - before loops. Or you could even calculate all `datetime.datetime.today()- datetime.timedelta(days=n)` before loops.

Comment: Thanks furas. Your advise does work. 
However, I got a new trouble in exporting to cvs files, please find the above edited post.

Comment: main rule in Stackoverflow - if you have new problem then create new post

Comment: you assign values from list `[0, 178, 356, 534]` to variable `n`, not `i`. So use `n` instead of `i`  - `data.to_csv("filename"+x+"@"+n+".csv")`

Comment: furas,  Thanks for your correction,  but the problem still exists

Comment: I will repeat again main rule - if you have new problem then create new post. Don't edit it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it change original questiona and OP ask new question

Comment: OK. Thanks for your remind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you for furas remainder, the following is the solution**

```
def get_data():

    # Every stock can loop on every periods
    stocks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','G','H']    

    periods = [0,178,356,534,712]

    for x in stocks:

        for n in periods:
            tws.reqHistoricalData(x)

            for _ in range(10): # repeat it only 10 times
                today = datetime.datetime.today()
                delta = datetime.timedelta(days=n)
                data = pd.DataFrame(reqHistoricalData(today-delta).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))

                if not data.empty:
                    data.to_csv("filename{}@{}.csv".format(x, n))
                    break # exit `for _` loop so it doesn't read again for the same period

                print("empty data for", x, str(n), '... reading again')
                tws.reqHistoricalData(x) # read again for the same period
```